# How to compute rank of IEnumerable<T> and store it in type T

Tags: c#, closures, captured-variable

I want to compute rank of element in an IEnumerable list and assign it to the member. But below code works only when called 1st time. 2nd time call starts from last rank value. So instead of output 012 and 012, I'm getting 012 and 345

```
    class MyClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Rank { get; set; }
    }

    public void SecondTimeRankEvaluvate()
    {
        MyClass[] myArray = new MyClass[] 
        {
            new MyClass() { Name = "Foo" },
            new MyClass() { Name = "Bar" },
            new MyClass() { Name = "Baz" }
        };

        int r = 0;
        var first = myArray.Select(s => { s.Rank = r++; return s; });

        foreach (var item in first)
        {
            Console.Write(item.Rank);
        }
        // Prints 012
        Console.WriteLine("");
        foreach (var item in first)
        {
            Console.Write(item.Rank);
        }
        // Prints 345
    }
```

I understand that the variable `r` is being captured (closure) and reused when called 2nd time. I don't want that behavior. Is there any clean way to compute rank and assign it?
Also `r` variable (in actual code) isn't in the same scope where `foreach` loop is present. It is in a function which returns `var first`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var first = myArray.Select((s, i) => { s.Rank = i; return s; });
```

Comment: It's an overload of `Select`.

Answer (score 3):

LINQ uses lazy evaluation and runs the `Select` part every time you use `myArray`.

You can force evaluation to happen only once by storing the result in a `List`.

Change

```
var first = myArray.Select(s => { s.Rank = r++; return s; });
```

to

```
var first = myArray.Select(s => { s.Rank = r++; return s; }).ToList();
```

Another way would be to join `myArray` with a new sequence using `Zip` every time, like this

```
var first = myArray.Zip(Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue), (s, r) =>
{
    s.Rank = r;
    return s;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah this will work. But is there any clean way to have deferred execution and ranking generated on the fly, instead of converting whole thing to list.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use LINQ if you're not querying the collection.

To update each item in an array, use a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
{
    myArray[i].Rank = i;
}
```

To update each item in an enumerable, use a `foreach` loop:

```
int r = 0;
foreach (var item in myArray)
{
    item.Rank = r++;
}
```